# Windbg javascript dump dml

Tags: windbg

In windbg using javascript there is a method:

host.diagnostics.debugLog(line, "\n");

Is there a way to output DML to print a hyperlink?

I'm thinking I want to output something like this:

```
<link cmd="!DumpObj /d 000000012c0cb8b0">!DumpObj /d 000000012c0cb8b0</link>
```

Comment: I don't think it's possible at the moment